# What does the function "return" do in my code?

Tags: haskell, io, return

**Type:**

```
data Command a = Command String (a -> IO a)
```

**Functions:**

```
iofunc :: String -> (a -> IO a) -> Command a
iofunc = Command

func :: String -> (a -> a) -> Command a
func s f = iofunc s (return . f)
```

Can someone explain how `(return . f)` type checks with `(a -> IO a)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no pattern matching going on in your code, so I assume you meant "type checks".

`return . f` is a function that takes an argument `x` and evaluates to `return (f x)`. `return` has the type `Monad m => a -> m a` and `f` has the type `a -> a`. Therefore we know that the type of `f x` is the same as the type of `x` and `return (f x)` then has the type `m a` where `a` is the type of `x` and `m` is a monad. In other words the type of `return . f` is `Monad m => a -> m a`, just like the type of `return` by itself.

The type required for the second argument to `iofunc` is `a -> IO a`. Since `IO` is a monad, that fits the type `Monad m => a -> m a` and thus `return . f` has the proper type to be passed as the second argument to `iofunc`. Therefore the code type checks.

Comment: Why doesn't (return . f) have to be a IO monad instead of any monad?

Comment: @Michiel `Monad m => a -> m a` means that it can produce any monad you want. So if you need an `IO`, it gives you an `IO` and if you'd need something else, it'd give you something else. Just like you can pass `42` (which has type `Num a => a`) to a function expecting an `Int` just as well as you can pass it to a function expecting an `Integer` or a `Double` for example.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean by "pattern matches" but in this case, `return :: a -> IO a`. notice that `f :: a -> a` so by threading the result of that on to `return` (or composing `return` with `f`, if you like) we go from `a -> a` to `a -> IO a`